# NSData型からバイト配列に

Tags: swift

swift2にて質問させてください。

TCP/IPまたはUDP通信を行いNSData型でdataは受信できているのですが
swift2において、byte配列というような型は存在しないのでしょうか。

byte配列に変換し、そのxx番目の配列のｘビット目を抜き出す・・・
当の処理を考えているのですが、どのようにしてNSData型のdataをbyte配列のようにして扱ってよいのかわからずに困っています。

初心者まるだしの質問で申し訳ないですが
何かアドバイスいただけると助かります。

Comment: [NSData Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/)を読みましょう。そこから、バイナリデータ処理のガイドへ行くリンクもあります。

Comment: それと、Swiftにもかかわらず、C言語のポインタの知識が必須なので、おぼつかなければ、しっかり復習しておくといいでしょう。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XcodeのPlaygroundで動かしてみてください。

```
import Foundation

let aString = "Hello, world!"　
// 文字列からNSDataインスタンスを作る。
if let aData: NSData = aString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
    // aDataのバイト数と同じ大きさの配列を作る。
    var aBuffer = Array<Int8>(count: aData.length, repeatedValue: 0)
    // aBufferにバイナリデータを格納。
    aData.getBytes(&aBuffer, length: aData.length) // &がアドレス演算子みたいに使える。
    for aChar in aBuffer {
        print("\(aChar)") // 各文字のutf-8の文字コードが出力される。
    }
}
```

出力：

> 72 101 108 108 111 44 32 119 111 114 108 100 33

`NSData`から、バイナリデータを抽出する簡単なサンプルコードです。本来は、C言語の配列に`getBytes()`するところですが、Swiftの配列（`Array`）で代用できる点に注目してください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
Array<Int8>・・・なるほど・・・byte型がない！と固執していました・・・。
バイトと同じサイズの配列を作ってあげればよかったのですね
ありがとうございます。

Comment: 整数型について、Swiftでは、`Int8`、`Int16`、`Int32`……と統一した名称を採用しているようです。浮動小数点数のほうは、`Float`と`Double`なんですけどね。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
いろいろ勉強が必要そうですね。。なにかいい参考本を探して勉強してみたいと思います。ありがとうございました。（返事が遅くなりすみません！）

Comment: @kanko 納得できる回答であれば、この回答を承認したほうがいいですよ。でないと、ずっとこの質問が未回答あつかいになっちゃうので。

Comment: すいません。ありがとうございます！
気を付けます。